# Attaching sources in IntelliJ IDEA for scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have Playframework 2 project with Scala (very small one). It uses [Scala Anorm](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaAnorm) library.

I have the code like this:

```
package models
..
import anorm.SqlParser._
...

val rowParser = scalar[Long]
```

So, I would like to see source of **scalar** method. Trying to attache the sources I have in my plaframework source folder, but IDEA just swallows my request and does nothing back.

I use last version of IDEA and Scala plugin. Is it bug, probably?

Comment: yes this appears to be broken

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Aha.. fixed.

So: I used to use 'attach source' in the top of the window editor - it does not work (I guess it is a bug - maybe related to the scala plugin, because usually it works).

But if try to attache sources to particular library - in "Project Structure -> Library -> +Attach File or Directories -> Sources" then it works.

Thanks.

Comment: This is STILL not working.. WHEN WILL THIS BE FIXED!

Comment: If install scala --with-src using homewbrew, you set source directory path File > Project structure -> libraries -> scala-library -> Sources -> '+' button -> /usr/local/opt/scala/idea/src -> then press ok.
Make sure when install scala with brew option --with-src, --with-docs.

Answer (score 13):

**First download source code :**

1.) Click on this link : http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html

2.) Choose any scala version.

3.) Now in the last section 'Other Resources' you can see 'Sources' link. Click on it to download. In my case (https://codeload.github.com/scala/scala/tar.gz/v2.11.7)

[image]

**Now point to this Source Code from IntelliJ.**

1.) Open Project Structure in IntelliJ. Shorcut (Cmd + DownArrow)

2.) Select Global Libraries from the left section.

3.) Then on right side, Under 'Scala Library' section. Click '+' and point to source directory. See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this tip, it helped me with another problem - i needed to also unzip the gzip

Answer (score 2):

To fix it we need to do some changes into IntelliJ IDEA platform. Most probably it will be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.

Comment: I really need this. When will this be fixed??

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I installed "Scala Imports Organizer", and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

for "automatically attaching source jars" when using Bloop and BSP you can add one line:

```
bloopExportJarClassifiers in Global := Some(Set("sources"))
```

to your `build.sbt`, also `sbt updateClassifiers`, also `Reload all BSP Projects` to refresh,  also `Invalidate Caches/Restart` to trigger indexing (if not done automatically)

[reference](https://scalacenter.github.io/bloop/docs/build-tools/sbt#download-dependencies-sources)