# Attach sources to IntelliJ project using Git url (git://github.com/...)

Tags: git, intellij-idea

IntelliJ has the option to attach sources to a project so that you can view how a precompiled method is implemented. Can you specify a read-only git repository as the source location?

[image]

For example I want to be able to say the sources for some classes are located in the git repository at git://github.com/project/sources.

***Details:*** IntelliJ 12, private Gitorious server

***Update:*** The git url is in the form `git://server/location`, http git urls are not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

1/ As mentioned in "[Attaching sources in IntelliJ IDEA for scala project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13520832/6309)", check if the *other* "attach source" menu works better:

> if try to attache sources to particular library - in "**`Project Structure -> Library -> +Attach File or Directories -> Sources`**", then it works.

2/ use https address instead of git url: `https://github.com/aUser/aProject.git`
(although that might not be available for [private gitorious repos](https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/PrivateRepositories), with only `git://gitorious.org/aUser/aProject.git`)

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those options allow me enter a URL as the path to the source.